# Many to many relation in spring framework

Tags: java, jpa

Currently I'm working on a Spring Framwork application to try out how it works.
I'm having trouble with a many to many relationship and inserting data into it.

As example I'm making something to store orders containing one or multiple items through a link table.

I would like to store one order at a time, including all products related to it (products are already existing). The problem is that when I try to store data, the orderId isn't stored in the `product_order` table and gives me the following error:

""Column 'ORDER_ID' cannot be null"".

Has anyone a clue about what i'm doing wrong? Or if it's just not possible this way.
SQL structure & Java code is at the end.

The way I try to store the data is:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{
  "code" : "Test",
  "statusId" : 2,
  "userId" : 1,
  "productOrders" : [ {
    "price" : 1.0,
    "amount" : 2,
    "product" : {
      "productId" : 1
    }
  }, {
    "price" : 2.0,
    "amount" : 3,
    "product" : {
      "productId" : 2
    }
  } ]
}' http://localhost:8080/order
```

This is the SQL structure i'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `USER_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_NAME` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `USER_BALANCE` DOUBLE UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`)
);


CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `PRODUCT_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PRODUCT_NAME` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_PRICE` DOUBLE UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION` VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (`PRODUCT_ID`)
);


CREATE TABLE  `order` (
  `ORDER_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ORDER_USER_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ORDER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ORDER_USER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ORDER_USER_ID`)
               REFERENCES `user` (`USER_ID`)
);


CREATE TABLE  `product_order` (
  `ORDER_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `AMOUNT` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `PRICE` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ORDER_ID`,`PRODUCT_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PRODUCT_ORDER_ORDER_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ORDER_ID`)
             REFERENCES `order` (`ORDER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PRODUCT_ORDER_PRODUCT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`PRODUCT_ID`)
             REFERENCES `product` (`PRODUCT_ID`)
);
```

And this are my classes (removed the getters/setters, left the annotations)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer productId;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Double price;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_NAME", nullable = false)

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_PRICE", nullable = false)

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "`order`")
public class Order implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer orderId;
    private Integer userId;
    private Set<ProductOrder> productOrders = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)

    @Column(name = "ORDER_USER_ID")

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "product_order")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.order",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.product",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")) })
public class ProductOrder implements java.io.Serializable {
    private ProductOrderId pk = new ProductOrderId();
    private Double price;
    private Integer amount;

    @EmbeddedId
    //Getter/setter for primaryKey (pk)

    @Transient
    //Link to product

    @Column(name = "PRICE")

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
}

@Embeddable
public class ProductOrderId implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Product product;
    private Order order;

    @ManyToOne
    //link to Product

    @ManyToOne
    //Link to Order
}
```

Comment: your question is about JPA, not about Spring.

Comment: Please check the definition of your order class. I can see table name order with apex

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that `product_order` has such field too:( How do you save your objects?

Comment: I've modified my code, that product_order has it's own dedicated primary key (auto generated), and creating them after a order is created. Not the way I would like, but it works as a temporary solution. Thanks for thinking along

Comment: Actually, usage of dedicated primary keys is good practice unlike of composite ones. So, I would to suggest to consider the solution as real and not temporary one :) gl!